# How can I redirect stderr output to a file using 'docker exec' command in bash?

Tags: bash, docker

The following command displays errors on stdout instead of redirecting to errors.log

```bash
$ docker exec -t mysql /bin/bash -c "mysqldump -u<user> -p<passwd> --databases db" 2> errors.log 1> dump.sql
```

when executing the following command passing fake arguments to generate errors, wrong db for instance

```bash
$ docker exec -t mysql /bin/bash -c "mysqldump -u<user> -p<passwd> --databases db"
```

and checking exit code, I get

```bash
$ echo "$?"
2
```

why isn't errors.log being populated with sdterr

I created a script to be executed by cron. I'm trying to redirect any errors to the file errors.log, but it's not working

Comment: As a follow-up: given that using `-t` will merge STDIN and STDERR, there is no way you can split them again after calling `docker exec`. What you can do is to split them *inside* the container, as in `bash -c "<command> 2> errors.log 1> dump.sql"` (redirect inside the double quotes) and map those files to the host